# continuously differentiable homogeneous function is positive on a closed curve encircling origin is positive in some neighborhood of origin

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ be a continuously differentiable homogeneous (i.e., $f(tx,ty)=tf(x,y)$ for all $t\ge 0$) function which positive on some closed curve encircling origin. Does it follow that $f$ is positive on the area that is enclosed by that closed curve?

Comment: Please recall in your post the definition of "homogeneous" and include your attempts.

Comment: Your question is quite interesting, and yet on this site a bare problem statement with no context can easily attract down votes and close votes. By editing your post to add just a bit of extra context such as suggested by @AnneBauval, you could greatly improve the post. Take a look at our suggestions for [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), with emphasis on [providing context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960).

Comment: I hope that my edit saves your question from being closed. A hint: If $f(x,y)\ge 0$, homogeneity implies that $f$ is positive on the whole ray $\{(tx,ty): t\ge 0\}$. Since the curve *encircles* the origin (do you have a clear definition for that?) this implies that $f$ is positive on all of $\mathbb R^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this should be the case (if I understand your question correctly). For any point $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ inside the area enclosed by the curve $C$, look at the ray
$$\ell : [0,\infty)\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^2, t\longmapsto t\cdot(x,y).$$

Since the curve $C$ is continuous, there has to be an intersection $(x',y')\in\mathbb{R}^2$ of $\ell$ and $C$ for some $t\in (0,\infty)$, i.e. $(x',y') = t\cdot (x,y)$. This means that

$$f(x,y) = f\left(\frac{1}{t}(x',y') \right)= \frac{1}{t} f(x',y')>0,$$
because by your assumption $f$ is positive all along $C$.